# Connector identification: 2-pin power connector

Tags: identification, connector

I try to identify this connector - it is used for power and 24V signals in a scientific device.

[image: CONNECTOR]

The dimensions of the plugged connectors are:

- 40.7 mm (full length)
- 6.6 mm (height)
- 13.65 mm  (width - 2 pins)

Pitch 6.x mm (~6.8)

Is there a structured process how for dealing with a question like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you unplug it and show us what the mating ends look like?

Comment: Also let us know the pitch (the distance between the pins) as accurately as you can.

Comment: And also, what device the connector is used in, make and model ideally (eg a 24v fan, but inside a computer power supply? a projector? a battery charge unit?)

Answer (score 0):

Those are [pin-and-socket connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=pin_socket_conn) (my site).

Specifically, they look like they use 0.093" contacts and a 6.3 mm pitch. If so, [they are made by multiple manufacturers](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=pin_socket_conn_093), including:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/standard_093) - Standard .093 Pin and Socket 6.3 (1r) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/z53dwtwz)
- TE - [Commercial .093 Pin and Socket 6.3 (1r)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY&DocType=CS&DocLang=English&DocFilename=ENG_CS_82181_SOFTSHELL_STANDARD_DENSITY_0508.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/3znnzzp8)

[image: Pin and socket connectors]

{Digikey}

If the contacts have a different diameter, please measure the inner diameter of the sockets, edit your question, and specify the diameter.

> Is there a structured process how for dealing with a question like this?

If I may, please let me direct you to my [Identiconn - Connector Identification Utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=classes).